# What gem can I use to handle state transitions in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What gem can I use to handle state transitions in rails 5? I think gems like workflow and state_machine are not compatible with Rails 5. Can you recommend with other gems? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MeriAlvarado - which one did you choose in the end?  Did it work out okay?  How well did it work in Rails 5?  I am about to implement one of these in a Rails 5.2 project and I am interested to hear your feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an opinion-oriented question, I suggest to use [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm). It is full of great features, works seemlessly with databases, have support to define callbacks for the transitions.

Comment: @MeriAlvarado Yes it will. In fact, I am using it with Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can try gem [state machine activerecord](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord) its supported with rails5.